# SQL Cartesian Select Boxes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP form that uses several select boxes that are populated by lookup tables.  In an effort to reduce the number of queries per page, I'm trying to find a way to create a cartesian product that would output the results like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        City       |   State    |    SchoolDistrict            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Adamsville        |     AL     |   Adamsville  Public Schools |
| Brownsville       |     AK     |   Baker-Cow USD              |
| Cowtown           |     AR     |   NULL                       |
| NULL              |     AZ     |   NULL                       |
| NULL              |     CA     |   NULL                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I could just loop through each field until it found null (or 0-length string).

When I tried:

```
SELECT a.City, b.State, c.SchoolDistrict FROM Cities a, State b, SchoolDistricts c
```

it returns:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|        City       |   State    |    SchoolDistrict            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Adamsville        |     AL     |   Adamsville  Public Schools |
| Brownsville       |     AK     |   Baker-Cow USD              |
| Cowtown           |     AR     |   Baker-Cow USD              |
| Cowtown           |     AZ     |   Baker-Cow USD              |
| Cowtown           |     CA     |   Baker-Cow USD              |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the original tables look like and how are they connected?

Comment: Basically, they're just single columns that are PK with values like those listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that I have come up with is

```
SELECT a.City, "City" type from Cities a 
UNION ALL
SELECT b.State, "State" from States b 
UNION ALL
SELECT c.SchoolDistrict, "SchoolDistrict" from SchoolDistricts c
```

This would be one query and you can check the value of the second column and do necessary operations.

Comment: That's actually much easier than what I originally envisioned as a solution.  Just requires a simple switch.  I'd upvote much more if I could.  Thanks!